# Vertically align comma with matrices in math mode

Tags: math-mode, matrices, punctuation

When I'm writing an equation with multiple matrices, the comma is still placed at normal text-height, which looks strange.

```
$\mathrm{f}\left(
\begin{bmatrix} a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} b_1\\b_2\end{bmatrix}\right)$
```

[image]

How can I automatically align it with the bottom of the vectors so it looks natural?

Comment: Im not sure it would lok very natural. What you show  is aligned on the base line (see the bottom of the `f`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the comma part of a matrix, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{f}\left(
\begin{bmatrix} a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix} \\,\end{matrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} b_1\\b_2\end{bmatrix}\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is close to what I wanted, but I still think the comma should be lower. Also another reminder to always post the exact problem I have, as I'm using a smallmatrix, which also makes the comma smaller... :)
If noone suggests a better answer, I will accept this one